# How to change dockers default network?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I created a new docker network ( macvlan  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/ )

How is it possible to tell docker to use this network as default (instead of bridge) when creating new container? I want to spare the --net for every new container.

Comment: Maybe there is a docker daemon config for this [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#linux-configuration-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `docker-compose`, you can use `networks`-key in `yml`-file. The following specifies mongo to use "pinguine" as default network:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    networks:
      - project-network

networks:
  project-network:
    name: pinguine
```

Answer (score -2):

Create or edit file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add the following configuration.

```
{
    "bridge": "my_network"
}
```

This way `my_network` would be used by default.

Comment: That doesn't work. Restarting deamon fails with  Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: bridge device with non default name pub_net must be created manually

Answer (score -2):

Docker provides different network drivers like bridge, host, overlay, and macvlan. bridge is the default.

To change your default network driver:

- Edit or create config file for docker daemon:

  ```
  # nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
  ```

  Add lines:

  ```
  {
    "default-address-pools":
      [
        {"base":"10.10.0.0/16","size":24}
      ]
  }
  ```

  Restart dockerd:

  ```
  # service docker restart
  ```
- Create a new network with the new network driver by using the --driver or -d parameter with your docker network create command
- Run your Docker image with the --network parameter to use your newly-created network.

  ```
  $ docker network create foo
  $ docker network inspect foo | grep Subnet
              "Subnet": "10.10.1.0/24"
  ```