# Docker Desktop - How to set docker daemon default network to "Default Switch" on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-network

In my case, Docker is configured to run Windows images. For the containers to access the external network, it is necessary to provide `--network "Default Switch"` on the command line that launches the container.

Docker desktop also provides a UI that launches containers from images with a simple "run" button.

However, in the Docker Desktop case, the default network is something else, and the resulting containers do not have access to the external network.

I have looked at the documentation for [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), which describes the `daemon.json` file, but there isn't an obvious setting that corresponds to the `--network` command line option.

On Windows, `--network "Default Switch"` refers to Hyper-V's virtual network switch configuration, and it's not clear how the IP-based configurations in `daemon.json` (e.g. `default-address-pool`) would correspond to the selection of a virtual switch since there can be more than one virtual switch that could (presumably) have overlapping IP ranges.

Q: Is it just impossible to run Windows containers from the Docker UI with an arbitrary network setting? Or how?

I have looked at several similar questions, but none seem to answer this.
Closest is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776695/how-to-change-dockers-default-network), asking a similar question on mac, but it has no upvoted answers and doesn't seem to answer the question either.